# Vue Canvas not loading images

Tags: vue.js, canvas

I am trying to build something with a canvas and 6 different images. My template looks like this:

```html
      <div>
        <img id="right_arm" src="../assets/body_parts/right_arm.png" style="display:none;" alt="">
        <img id="head" class="char-img" style="display:none;" src="../assets/images/body_parts/head.png" />
        <img id="left_arm" src="../assets/body_parts/left_arm.png" style="display:none;" alt="">
        <img id="legs" src="../assets/body_parts/legs.png" style="display:none;" alt="">
        <img id="shoes" src="../assets/body_parts/feet.png" style="display:none;" alt="">
        <img id="torso" src="../assets/body_parts/torso.png" style="display:none;" alt="">
        <canvas width="400" height="600" id="my-canvas"></canvas>
      </div>
```

Then inside mounted I try to load all of the images and put them onto my canvas like so

```js
  mounted(){
    console.log("Building Canvas")
    var canvas = document.getElementById("my-canvas")
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")
    var head = document.getElementById("head")
    var left_arm = document.getElementById("left_arm")
    var shoes = document.getElementById("shoes")
    var legs = document.getElementById("legs")
    var torso = document.getElementById("torso")
    var right_arm = document.getElementById("right_arm")

    var scale = 0.55; // 0.55
    var head_scale = 0.50;


    ctx.drawImage(right_arm, 180, 42, right_arm.width * scale, right_arm.height * scale)
    ctx.drawImage(torso, 70, 150, torso.width * scale, torso.height * scale)
    ctx.drawImage(left_arm, 65, 137,  left_arm.width * scale, left_arm.height * scale)
    ctx.drawImage(head, 83, 0, head.width * head_scale, head.height * head_scale)
    ctx.drawImage(shoes, 85, 435, shoes.width * scale, shoes.height * scale)
    ctx.drawImage(legs, 74, 326, legs.width * scale, legs.height * scale)
  }
```

The problem here is that the canvas wont load any of the images. I know this has something to do with me trying to fetch the images before they are loaded because if I wrap whats inside of `mount()` in a `setTimeout()` function and set it to 1 second. It all works. So My question is how can I make it so it waits for all of the images to properly load before fetching them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fix for this was adding a `v-on:load="numOfLoadedImgs++"` even handler and a data point called `numOfLoadedImgs: 0`

When all images finish loaded the count will be 6 and I have a watch method that then loads the canvas when the number is equal to 6

`<img v-on:load="numOfLoadedImgs++" id="torso" src="" style="display:none;" alt="">`

```js
  data(){
    return{
     numOfLoadedImgs: 0

    }
  },
  watch:{
    numOfLoadedImgs(num){
      if(num === 6){
        this.loadCanvas();
        return num
      }
      return num
    }
  },
  methods:{
    loadCanvas(){}
  }
```